# Astra J 2013 leak

Tags: oil-leak, vauxhall, astra

i have a massive leak on my astra 2013. I have attached the picture next to the filter. Can someone please tell what this is and how serious of an issue it is? [image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

As with most oil leaks, it's not *serious* as in you wouldn't have to get it fixed today to keep your car running. If you do put it off, the only thing you'd really need to do is ensure the oil is good (topped off) on a regular basis (ie: at least weekly). In the military we'd classify an oil leak at three different levels: Class 1, 2, & 3

- Class 1: Oil film can be see - not a big deal, but keep an eye on it.
- Class 2: Oil forms a drip, but no drip is seen falling - needs to get it in the shop, but not deadlined (unusable for work).
- Class 3: Oil drips from some part of the engine - Deadlined vehicle ... cannot be used again until the leak is fixed.

Your oil leak appears to be at a Class 1 level, though to be fair, I can't see the bottom of the vehicle.

Yes, there's a lot of oil/gunk on the vertical face of the engine. That's not where the oil is coming from, though. (Note: I *believe* the image is looking down on the engine?) Oil doesn't leak up hill, only down. Your leak is coming from somewhere above the top of where the image ends. The best way to figure it out is to clean everything very well, then see (over a couple of days) where the oil is coming from. Until you figure it out, you won't know what you need to fix.